Django and apache2(ssl) production setup
I have three web applications currently running in production on Apache2 with SSL. I plan to containerize all of these applications (a Django app) using Docker while continuing to use Apache2 for serving it. Previously, Apache2 ran the Django application with WSGI. how to configure Apache2 (which will also be running in Docker) to work with this Dockerized Django application.
I Tried running in manage.py runserver but it is only for development and configured docker ip in apache2 it is running but on production we cannot use that right.
